# Replacing Manifest.in with pyproject.toml

Tags: python-poetry, pyproject.toml

Previously, when defining how to build a Python package, you can include folders using a line in `Manifest.in`:

```
recursive-include my_package/assets *
```

However, I would like to `poetry` and the associated `pyproject.toml`, instead of `Manifest.in`.

Can `pyproject.toml` replace `Manifest.in`? Alternatively, how can `poetry` be used with `Manifest.in`?

Comment: Semantics: You are not replacing `MANIFEST.in` with `pyproject.toml`, this does not make much sense. You can change the _build-backend_ of your project from `setuptools` to `poetry` though, that makes sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, poetry aims to completely obsolete the use of `Manifest.in` files. The assumption is that every file that is part of your package should also be part of the distributable. So, as long as you follow a more or less standard project structure, Things Should Just Work™.

And if your package happens to be structured in a strange way, or you want to package files that for some reason aren't in the source folder, you can use the [include and exclude](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude) sections for that.

Comment: To add to this: poetry excludes `__pycache__` folders, and whatever is ignored by `git` as well by default.